# SSRS call to stored procedure fails, Cannot find user 'dbo'

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I've got a SSRS report that is calling a stored procedure in my database.

Locally everything works, I am connecting with Windows authentication locally to hit the database and there are no problems.

When the SSRS report is deployed it's set up to use a different login, and this login has the correct role to grant execute on stored procedures. However, when trying to view the report on SSRS server I get this message:

> Cannot find the user 'dbo', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

If I remove the role that allows the grant execute rights I get a more specific error saying that I don't have permission to execute the stored procedure. But once this role is put back on the user account SSRS runs as it goes back go showing an error

> Cannot find the user 'dbo'

The role I have that is granted execute rights is granted by 'dbo' user, this is the database owner. I have found things online saying that it's possible that a database backup messed up some user logins. I have checked, and the database owner sid is the same as the sysuser sid for name = 'dbo', so I do not think this is the problem.

Does anyone else know what I might be able to try?

EDIT: Details on stored procedure: it is a simple select with some inner joins.
At the end of the stored procedure is the following, granting access to the role my SSRS user is part of:

```
GRANT EXECUTE
    ON OBJECT::[dbo].[Application_LoadData] TO [SSRSUserRole]
    AS [dbo];
```

Comment: Probably something inside the stored procedure.  Can you simplify and post a repro?

Comment: The sproc is nothing crazy, at the bottom it grants access to this sproc to the user role the SSRS user uses. This same sproc is used in the API, running as the same user, and it works there. I'm not sure why the SSRS report is failing with it.

Comment: "At the end of the stored proc is the following, granting access to the role my SSRS user is part of:" - is this grant within the stored procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A stored procedure includes all statements in the batch after the CREATE PROCEDURE.  So a proc like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_FOO
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM FOO
END

GRANT EXECUTE ON USP_FOO TO SOMEUSER AS DBO;
```

Will attempt to execute to GRANT every time the procedure is run, and will fail when not run by dbo.

The script to create the procedure should have a batch separator before the grant.  eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_FOO
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM FOO
END

GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON USP_FOO TO SOMEUSER AS DBO;
```

Comment: I will put 'GO' after my END and before Grant Execute and see if that works

Comment: That did it! I added 'GO' before the Grant Execute portion and now it works. Thank you so much

Comment: The granting permissions at end of SP was what was causing the issue for me.  The SP would execute and return results then get the error.  Which makes sense since that is order it was in, but error was not clear at all on what it didnt have permissions for just the generic error.